# How to set combobox item select for whole row in Wpf

Tags: wpf, combobox, selecteditem

Here is my combobox datatemplate

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel  KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Flag}" Height="25"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
```

It works fine , i want to select row when mouse is anywhere in row area, and not only when it is just over data.

Thanks[image]

ok, its solved by @Jehof , thanks. And second question is "why it does not work if i set Template?"
like this

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
            <!--<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>-->

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                        <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" BorderThickness="1">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundHighlighted}"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BorderBrushHighlighted}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

If remove   `<Setter Property="Template">` ...  part it works!

---

@Jehof  and why it does not work  if i set Template?

```
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
                <!--<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>-->

                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                            <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" BorderThickness="1">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundHighlighted}"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BorderBrushHighlighted}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the ItemContainerStyle to your ComboBox with a HorizontalContentAlignment set to Stretch.

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
  </Style >
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```